# How to create generic Java interface typed with another generic Java interface?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, persistence, dao

The goal of our approach is to introduce interfaces to our existing DAO and model classes. The model classes are identified by resource-IDs of various types and the resource-IDs are not just random numbers, but carry semantics and behavior. Thus, we have to represent resource-IDs by objects rather than primitive types.

Current approach for resource-IDs:

```java
interface ResourceId<T> {
  T get();
}
class UserId implements ResourceId<String> {
  public String get();
}
```

Current approach for our resources/models:

```java
interface Resource<I extends ResourceId> {
  I id();
}
class User implements Resource<UserId> {
  public UserId id();
}
```

---

I am struggling finding a working solution for our DAO classes. Here are some approaches I tried but failed:

**=== Option 1 ===**
fails with:
`error: > expected`
multiple levels of generic types seem forbidden in Java

```java
interface Dao<R extends Resource<I extends ResourceId>> {
  R findById(I id);
  void save(R u);
}
class UserDao implements Dao<User> {
  public User findById(UserId id);
  public void save(User u);
}
```

**=== Option 2 ===**
fails with:
`UserDao is not abstract and does not override abstract method <R>save(R) in Dao`
Also Dao<UserId> looks stupid. UserDao should be a Dao<User> object.

```java
interface Dao<I extends ResourceId> {
  <R extends Resource<I>> R findById(I id);
  <R extends Resource<I>> void save(R u);
}
class UserDao implements Dao<UserId> {
  public User findById(UserId id);
  public void save(User u);
}
```

**=== Option 3 ===**
fails with:
`UserDao is not abstract and does not override abstract method <I>findById(I) in Dao`
Even if it worked, I is not bound by the ResourceId actually implemented by R.

```java
interface Dao<R extends Resource> {
  <I extends ResourceId> R findById(I id);
  void save(R u);
}
class UserDao implements Dao<User> {
  public User findById(UserId id);
  public void save(User u);
}
```

**=== Option 4 ===**
compiles.
However #findById in UserDao would have to take a generic parameter of type ResourceId instead of UserId. Also, inside of the implementation of #findById we would have to cast the result of #get() to String.
Generally the problem is that the type of ResourceId is not bound by the ResourceId actually implemented by R.

```java
interface Dao<R extends Resource> {
  R findById(ResourceId id);
  void save(R u);
}
class UserDao implements Dao<User> {
  public User findById(ResourceId id);
  public void save(User u);
}
```

**=== Option 5 ===**
compiles.
However Dao<User, UserId> looks stupid. The information which ResourceId we want to use (i.e. UserId) is already available in the implementation of the Resource (i.e. User). Is there no cleaner way?

```java
interface Dao<R extends Resource, I extends ResourceId> {
  R findById(I id);
  void save(R u);
}
class UserDao implements Dao<User, UserId> {
  public User findById(UserId id);
  public void save(User u);
}
```

Any ideas how to properly solve this?

Comment: `interface Resource<I extends ResourceId> {` is a raw type. You need another type variable, e.g. `interface Resource<T, I extends ResourceId<T>> {`

Comment: @AndyTurner: Thanks for the comment! Ok, I think I get it. Java cannot imply the type of generic types used in an interface. So for the resources/models, I will have to create the interface as `Resource<T, I extends ResourceId<T>>` and an appropriate implementation `User implements Resource<String, UserId>`. For the the DAO classes, I will have to create the interface as `Dao<T, I extends ResourceId<T>, R extends Resource<I>>` and an appropriate implementation `UserDao implements Dao<String, UserId, User>`. Ok, I think I get it, but I'm still disappointed at Java that there is no cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

Your option # 1 will work just fine by tweaking it appropriately. First add the `ResourceId` generic type specification to your `Dao` declaration:

```
    static interface Dao<I extends ResourceId<?>, R extends Resource<I>> {
        R findById(I id);
        
        void save(R u);
    }
```

... and then do the same with the `Dao` subclasses:

```
    static class UserDao implements Dao<UserId, User> {
        public User findById(UserId id) { return null; }
        
        public void save(User u) {}
    }
```

Since you don't need to know what is the generic type of a `ResourceId` (`<T>`) within the context of the `Resource` class, you can just dismiss it there with a wildcard:

```
    static interface Resource<I extends ResourceId<?>> {
        I id();
    }
```

Finally, the full code would compile as:

```
public class NestedGenerics {
    
    static interface ResourceId<T> {
        T get();
    }
    
    static class UserId implements ResourceId<String> {
        public String get() { return null; } 
    }
    
    static interface Resource<I extends ResourceId<?>> {
        I id();
    }
    
    static class User implements Resource<UserId> {
        public UserId id() { return null; } 
    }
    
    static interface Dao<I extends ResourceId<?>, R extends Resource<I>> {
        R findById(I id);
        
        void save(R u);
    }
    
    static class UserDao implements Dao<UserId, User> {
        public User findById(UserId id) { return null; }
        
        public void save(User u) {}
    }
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56195065)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Marco, yes, that definitely helps. Thanks for taking the time and giving a detailed answer! Yeah, I thought something like that would be necessary (see Option 5), I just hoped that there could be a cleaner way. What I mean is that now in our code when I need a UserDao, I will pass around a `Dao<UserId, User>` which looks a bit verbose. Particularly given that I thought Java could imply the type "UserId" from User. No biggy of course, just hoped that there was a cleaner approach. Thanks again for clarifying! :)